# LaTex: Problem with includepdf. No signature after include

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have a problem with includepdf in LaTex.
I have a document with a signature that I want to include in my LaTex document, but after including it the signature is missing. I have the same problem with includegraphics or with pdfs that you can fill in. Then the filled text is also missing.

Unfortunately I don't know how to upload the "Hello.pdf" with the signature here.

For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, german, oneside, openright]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
    This is a test Pdf.
    \includepdf{Hallo.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Best regards

Comment: Including a pdf form is tricky. As a workaround, you can print it to pdf first and then include the "printed" pdf. You won't be able to alter the fields, but at least the previous text should be visible

Comment: Thanks that works, I could have thought of it myself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including a pdf form is tricky. `pdfpages` usually destroys a lot of things, like links etc.

However as a workaround, you can print the form to pdf first and then include the "printed" pdf. You won't be able to alter the fields, but at least the previous text will be visible.